# Display Soft Input Panel (SIP) on WP7 programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, soft-input-panel

How can I programmatically display the soft input panel (SIP)/keypad, via code. (I dont have a text-box on which I can specify the InputScope).

Comment: Why do you want to? Users will expect that the SIP is for entering text in to a textbox (or similar).

Comment: I want to display the text in textblock.

In addition, the problem with relying on the textbox is that the SIP is displayed only when the textbox has focus. I have only one UI that updates based on what the user is typing, other elements update based on this main input. What I am trying to work around is the fact that if the user clicks elsewhere on my screen, the SIP disappears and the user has to click inside the textbox again to display it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Jeff Blankenburgs 31 Days of Windows Phone 7](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-10-InputScope-TextBoxes.aspx):

> Sometimes, you want to get keyboard
>   input from your user, even when you
>   don’t want to present them with an
>   actual TextBox.  There’s probably
>   plenty of ways around this, but I’ve
>   been using a handy one that is simple
>   to accomplish.  (If you’re searching
>   for a reason to do this, think of a
>   game of Hangman.  I don’t want the
>   keyboard visible always, but I also
>   don’t want a TextBox on the screen.)
>
> Put a button on your page.
>
> Put a TextBox on your page, but make sure it’s hidden from the user’s view.
>
> Either position it off screen, make it completely transparent (and in the absolute background), or some other method that allows it to get added to your visual tree, but doesn’t let the user see it.
>
> Set an event handler on your button that sets Focus() to the hidden textbox when it’s clicked.
>
> That’s it!  This will allow you to show the keyboard without the user seeing a textbox.seeing a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XNA, you can use [Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975190.aspx) but i'm not sure that that is allowed if you're doing silverlight.  But i will second the comment on "why?" because if you don't have a textbox, how are you showing the user what they are typing?