# hello, as you can open the keyboard wp7 with c #

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display Soft Input Panel (SIP) on WP7 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939389/display-soft-input-panel-sip-on-wp7-programmatically)

I'm doing an application that must display the keyboard, and could not discover an event to perform this function in c #.
I would be of much help you can acesorar this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to TextBox and keyboard will show:

```
TextBox1.Focus();
```